# Which css element in style.css for theme 2011

Tags: css, wordpress

Which css element in style.css for theme 2011 using for page title and page content for page.php?

Comment: *Not a real question:* It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help, see the [FAQ].

Comment: epic question must say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question you can use Google Chrome's Inspect Element feature.

Simply right click on any element on the page and choose "Inspect Element"

You will then see in the Styles pane on the right the answers to all of your questions. You can even edit the css live right there! (notice that it tells you the file and line number of each style "style.css:38")

[image]